# How to get a list of values out of a 2D point plot saved as pdf with Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have data that is only accessible as a 2D point plot saved as pdf-file and need the raw data (the x and associated y values) out of it.

Is there any way I can do this with Mathematica, so that I am able to use the data internally for evaluation?

An [example plot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kgny29eM8q2oIj7BopP-dx0HQ4E449P_/view?usp=sharing) to Import would be (ListPlot of x^2; x=0-10)

Comment: http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach you could take with Mathematica

```
img = First@Import[
              "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Kgny29eM8q2oIj7BopP-dx0HQ4E449P_"];
mb = MorphologicalBinarize[img];
cn = ColorNegate[Closing[mb, DiskMatrix[0.5]]];
coords = Flatten[Last /@ ComponentMeasurements[cn, {"Centroid"}], 1];
ListPlot[coords]
```

[image]

You will have to appropriately scale the coordinates if you want them to exactly match `y = x^2`.

Comment: thanks for the input!
I'd like to adopt my question, as I've experimented further: Is there any way to locate the positions of certain objects (as triangles, dots, ...) in a pdf imported to mathematica?

Comment: The code in the answer identifies the coordinates of circles or dots. It can be adapted to do the same for triangles, rectangles or other simple geometric shapes. If the image has shapes of different sizes or a mix of different shapes or overlapping shapes or a background that is not relatively uniform then it will not work accurately without significant changes. For those situations a neural net may be a better solution provided you have sufficient representative training data.